# Can't upload original firmware to D-Link DIR-330

Tags: firmware

I was trying to install dd-wrt on it but it didn't work well.
So I'm trying to load the original D-link firmware...
I can always get to the emergency firmware upload page after resetting the router but whenever I try uploading the firmware it hangs for a couple seconds and times out... doesn't respond to pings either.
I've tried both ver 1.10 and 1.12 of the firmware here http://www.dlink.com/us/en/support/product/dir-330-ethernet-vpn-router-8-port-10-100-switch

Answer (score 0):

On the back of your router, there will be a little reset button. This thing:

[image]

Stick a paperclip in there and it will reset to factory default. This will also reset the firmware.

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the firmware"? I highly doubt a factory reset will do anything to the firmware.

Comment: When you restore your router to factory default it restores to to *exactly* as it came from the factory. At least, when I did this to my router (a D-Link DIR-655) it did.

Comment: It resets the NVRAM (settings, etc.), but it does not reset the firmware back to the version shipped by the factory. If you flash it with a new firmware, you can reset it all you want but it'll still have the new firmware.

Comment: did the 30/30/30 reset... held reset for 30 seconds while power on, unplugged while holding reset still for 30 seconds, then turned it back on with power on and held for another 30 seconds... also with power off held reset and plugged it in for another 10 seconds..

Comment: On my router (also a D-Link) it works, guess it's model specific. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Power off the router, and press and hold reset button for 10-15 sec (then release reset button).
2. Set IP address of the PC to static address in 192.168.x.x range (for example `192.168.2.1`).
3. Open http://192.168.0.1 in browser. Upload a text file containing the string "HD0" (without quotation marks).
4. Wait until `ping 192.168.0.2` responds. Then send the firmware file to the router using something like `tftp.exe -i 192.168.0.2 firmware.bin` ([Windows TFTP client](http://www.tftp-server.com/tftp-client.html)) or `tftp -m binary 192.168.0.2 -c put firmware.bin` ([Linux `tfp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tftp)), substituting "firmware.bin" with the one you want to record in the router.

It refers specifically to the DIR-330.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you wrote: 1) Which one the text file content should be: just `HD0` or `"HD0" !!!` (or is it some other combination)? 2) Then reboot router? 3) wait until it responds to ping on .2 IP? (I'm just trying to decipher what sure looks like an promising answer but is very hard to read)

Comment: I really do not know much English. 
The text file contains HD0.

Comment: I really do not know much English. 
The text file contains HD0. router power off? press button reset, not release reset button power on router. Wait 10 - 15 sec and release reset buton, wait ping 192.168.0.1 ( before set static address in PC 192.168.10 or 192.168.XX ), open in browser http://192.169.0.1 and choce this text file, press upload... And wait ping 192.168.0.2 !!! Then send the firmware file -i TFTP 192.168.0.2 firmware.bin, or the one you want to record in the router. 
It refers specifically to the DIR-330.

Comment: Ok, this was much more understandable (and very different from the original, even with the order of steps etc, so to me it is not just about your English skills but also overall written expression). I did more than I should have done and edited the answer based on what you now wrote, I hope I got it right... and anyway, you can always further edit it yourself in case the procedure still isn't correct.

Comment: TFTP -i 192.168.0.2 firmware.bin

Comment: Yes, figured that you meant it that way... My edit is actually still pending peer review so it might not be visible to you yet...

Comment: Power off the router, and press reset button and hold reset button, hold reset button  and power ON the router and for 10-15 sec (then release reset button).  ... (for example 192.168.0.3)

Comment: You can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1124910/edit) your own post from the "edit" link right underneath it.